# grouping list by condition dependent on other list

Tags: java, java-stream

Streams grouping is clear for me when it comes to property of objects that create stream, but how to group objects by condition which is dependent on other list. Below is code with nested loops which I would like to transform to stream solution.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LocalDate n = LocalDate.from(LocalDate.now());

        List<LocalDate> groupingDates = Arrays.asList(n, n.plusDays(10), n.plusDays(20));
        List<Item> itemsToBeGrouped = Arrays.asList(
                //should go to group labeled by "n"
                new Item(n, n.plusDays(1)),
                new Item(n.minusDays(5), n.plusDays(7)),

                //should go to group labeled by "n.plusDays(10)"
                new Item(n.plusDays(5), n.plusDays(11)),

                //should go to group labeled by "n.plusDays(20)"
                new Item(n.plusDays(15), n.plusDays(20)));

        Map<LocalDate, List<Item>> groupedItems = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for(Item i : itemsToBeGrouped) {
            for (LocalDate date : groupingDates) {
                if(isActiveOnDate(i, date)) {
                    if (!groupedItems.containsKey(date)) {
                        groupedItems.put(date, new ArrayList<>());
                    }
                    groupedItems.get(date).add(i);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(groupedItems);
    }

    static boolean isActiveOnDate(Item item, LocalDate date) {
        return !item.start.isAfter(date) && !item.end.isBefore(date);
    }
}

public class Item{
    public LocalDate start;
    public LocalDate end;

    public Item(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" +
                "start=" + start +
                ", end=" + end +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your problems? You can just use [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) with a suitable key (which means pass a function that iterates over those dates like you are doing...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the same in the `groupingBy` lambda, as you do in your `for-loop`, select the first date that the item matches, and then use that as a key:

```
Map<LocalDate, List<Item>> groupedItems = itemsToBeGrouped.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> groupingDates.stream()
        .filter(d -> isActiveOnDate(i, d))
        .findFirst() // Optional<Date>
        .get() // will throw if nothing matches
    ));
```

Comment: I recommend `findFirst()` over `findAny()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "inconsistent data"? any example?

Comment: @Nikolas nevermind, I read something in OP's code that isn't even there. `findFirst` should be preferred for consistency. So you're completly right, I've edited :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Map<LocalDate, List<Item>> groupedItems2 = itemsToBeGrouped.stream()
            .flatMap(x -> groupingDates.stream()
                    .filter(y -> isActiveOnDate(x, y))
                    .map(y -> new SimpleEntry<>(x, y)))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    SimpleEntry::getValue,
                    LinkedHashMap::new,
                    Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
```